# using facebook SDK in android , How to invite friend?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

It's the first time to work with facebook SDK in android , so after signed in my application using facebook ! i retrieved my invitable_friends and show them in a listView

```
       new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me/invitable_friends",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response.getRawResponse());
                        JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("data");
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            String id = jsonObject.optString("id");
                            String name = jsonObject.optString("name");
                            String url = jsonObject.optJSONObject("picture").optJSONObject("data").optString("url");
                            Person person = new Person(id,name,url);
                            person.setId(id);
                            person.setName(name);
                            person.setUrl(url);
                            list.add(person);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    listView.setAdapter(new FriendsAdapter(getApplicationContext(),list));
```

now i need to send invitation to my friend to use my application when clicked .

so i handle that on **OnItemClickListener**

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            String appLinkUrl;

                            appLinkUrl = "Application Link";

                            if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
                                AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                                        .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
                                        .build();
                                AppInviteDialog.show(FriendsList.this, content);
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
```

and i keep track with the process success or failure

```
 appInviteDialog = new AppInviteDialog(this);
    appInviteDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<AppInviteDialog.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AppInviteDialog.Result result) {
            Log.d("Yehia","onSuccess result = "+ result.getData().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.d("Yehia","onError message = "+ e.getMessage());
        }
    });

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

but Unfortunately always **onError** Called ! 
i know that i have some misunderstanding .
can any body help me ! 
NOTE : my link application does not work yet !
thanks in advance .

Comment: Please post your full logcat @Mohamed Yehia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually i was using SDK v4.11.0 when i switch it to v4.0.0 it works.